# How do you modify a waveform graph in labview to display the time axis in milliseconds instead of seconds?

Tags: labview, waveform

In the following LabView diagram:

[image]

The waveform I get looks triangular, but I am expecting it to look more like square pulse waves.  How can I change the time axis to display in milliseconds instead of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the display of the x-format to %<%3u>T, this is selectable from the properties.

[image]

This however will add a decmal sign to the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, but you can change the display format of the X-axis.  Right-click on the indicator, select Properties and, on the Display Format tab, set the type to Floating point, Digits to 3 and Precision Type to Digits of precision.  Then, double-click the 0.1 on your X-axis and set it to 0.001.  You can make the X scrollbar visible to be able to see the whole graph.

You also appear to have missed the point on the selected frequency and width indicators in another post.  You don't need them; you can make the Digital Display visible.

Comment: You can do a conversion to ms in the wiring behind simply by unbundling the data line to the graph, multiplying the Y-data by 1000, and then re-bundling it back into the graph.  You could even make a selector on the front page to choose between sec/ms, etc.